# Proof verification: Show that the Frobenius map is surjective.

Tags: proof-verification, field-theory

I would like to prove the following but I would like someone to check my proof.

> For an algebraically closed field $K$ with characteristic $p$, the Frobenius map $F(x) = x^p$ is surjective

What I know:

1. Frobenius map is always an injective homomorphism.
2. Frobenius map is surjective if $|K|$ is finite.

My guess is that I need to use properties of algebraically closed field. I tried contradiction. Namely, suppose there exists $y\in K$ such that no $x\in K$ satisfies that $x^p = y$. This implies that the polynomial $X^p - y$ has no root, contradicting the fact that $K$ is algebraically closed.

Is my proof correct? Thank you.

Comment: Looks right to me. What is your concern?

Comment: @Mosquite Just want another pair of eyes ^ ^

Comment: My only suggestion is to start with the assumption that $F$ is not surjective and then derive your assumption that there exists $y \in K$ in such that there is no $x \in K$ such that $x^p = y$.

Comment: @Mosquite Yes, you are right. That makes more sense. Thank you!